# Difference between Android in built Geocoder and Google Geocoding API

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

Can anybody tell me exact difference between [Android Geocoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html)  and [Android Google Geocoder API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)

As far I know, Android Geocoder is platform in-built class and gives less result compare to APIs and also less reliable.

Is there any hard limit/quota for in-built Geocoder class ?

Answer (score 3):

Android Geocoder is built in class and has no quota limits.

Geocoding API is a http request and has 2500 QPD quota. Geocoding seem to be more reliable.

Comment: Are you sure Android Geocoder has no quota limit at all ? Can you please refer some relevant link or document for the same.

Comment: @Verma That difference is ok. But, is there any other differences?

Comment: Hey @Verma, I would also be interested in a relevant link stating that Android Geocoder has no quota limits, just to be really sure.

Answer (score 0):

Geocoder is just "a class for handling geocoding and reverse geocoding".
According to the documentation:
"The Geocoder class requires a backend service that is not included in the core android framework. The Geocoder query methods will return an empty list if there no backend service in the platform. Use the isPresent() method to determine whether a Geocoder implementation exists."

Google Geocoding API is the API, the backend service in the platform. You can use it without Geocoder class.

Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder